# Separate identity column CodeFirst mvc

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations, code-first

Im developing a mvc5 application using CodeFirst approach. Here is the modal class

```
public class Feeder
{
    [Key]   
    public int FeederId { get; set; }

    public string FeederName { get; set; }

    public string FeederCode { get; set; }


    public DateTime StatusChangeDate { get; set; }

    public int CreateBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public int EditBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime EditDate { get; set; }
}
```

Here for 'FeederCode' i want to generate a string that increments for every record. The string should be like this.

BMK15FEDR00001

Here 'BMK' and 'FEDR' are fixed. But 15(last 2 digits of 2015) will change based on the year. Since this is 2015 it should be 15 and for next year records it's 16. '00001' should increment for every record as 00002, 00003....

I searched for this but couldn't come up with the correct approach. All help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not making it a computed value?
You said that `BMK` and `FEDR` are constant, you can extract the year from `CreatedDate`, and as far as the last part, your `FeederId` is already set to auto-gen by default so SQL is making that for you.
Now your computed value should be saved as:
 `"BMK" + CreatedDate.ToString("yy") + "FEDR" + FeederId;

and this is what you save in the `FeederCode` value.

Hope that's what you meant.

If u'd also like each year codes to start from 1 again you should set a composite primary key with the other value being the year. and you can also reset the Identity value, you can read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) how it's done (part c).

**Update regarding the id value:**

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Person.AddressType', RESEED, 10);
GO
```

as decirbed in the attached link:

> The following example forces the current identity value in the AddressTypeID column in the AddressType table to a value of 10. Because the table has existing rows, the next row inserted will use 11 as the value, that is, the new current increment value defined for the column value plus 1.

If that's not important to you I advice you to just avoid it. if it is you can use it for your needs. the best way to implement this is to trigger a SQL event that each year will reset the auto-identifier.

Comment: Yes that worked. Thank you very much! Could you pls further explained me what to do if each year starts from 1 again since im confused with that scenario. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad that works for you. What I meant was that in if it's important to you that each year the identifier id `FeederId` will reset back to 1. i.e in 2015 you have this record `BMK15FEDR05371` in case you want 2016 records to start from 1 again like this `BMK16FEDR00001` you should reset to identifier to 1 (this value is auto-generated by the sql engine). to so you can use the scripted I've added to my answer.